# Restart/Load another Fragment | Android

Tags: java, android, fragment

I tried implement tab view in my app. This is the code that I used 
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

I created my fragment and I can go change between them. In the main activity I have menu the default menu (three points up right corner).
My question is how can I make that when I click on button in the menu one tab will be update/refresh/become another framgent, The name and the fragment. (I override onOptionsItemSelected..)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it help for someone. The solution is to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter and not FragmentPagerAdapter.
and manipulate the getItem function.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to use a menu item to switch to a specific tab, right?

To change to a tab grammatically you can use setSelectedNavigationItem like this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
//this will put the screen to the first tab (tab at index 0).
```

If you want to do this with a menu item just put it in onMenuItemSelected.

Let me know if you need me to explain in more detail.

=================EDIT=====================

ah i think i understand, so replace the current tab fragment with another one in its place?
I think you can do that by:

```
    actionBar.removeTabAt(position); //position is the current tab position.
    actionBar.addTab(tab, position); //insert a new tab at that position
```

if its not selected after you insert it, try this:

```
    actionBar.addTab(tab, position, setSelected)
```

*i did not test this, so let me know if it does not work.*

Comment: No I correct myself. I dont want to select another tab.
but Load another  fragment into specific tab.

Comment: this other fragment that you want to load, is it to be inserted as a tab? or replace the current tab than if you click on a tab the fragment that was added gets removed?

Comment: not inserted as a new tab. I want when I click on the the menu button..
One fragment will be remove and new fragment will be in this tab.
(Something like replace the fragments for a tab)

Comment: I tried this thing but this not help. cause the new tab that create gets the same fragment. I post the solution. Use FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Thanks!!

Comment: oh i see, sorry didn't see that. glad you found it, good stuff.